# file upload error blank?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file by selecting it with an html form then sending it to the php to do the actual upload and storing on the server. But when I test it I get a completely blank error so I can't figure out what's wrong.

here's the html:

```
<form action="libs/sc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="c_img1" tabindex="0" /> 
    <input type="file" name="c_img2" tabindex="1" /> 
    <input type="file" name="c_img3" tabindex="2" /> 
    <input type="file" name="c_img4" tabindex="3" /> 
    <input type="file" name="c_img5" tabindex="4" /> 
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and the php:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["c_img$i"]["tmp_name"],"../images/cards/".$i)) {
        die('File Error: ' . $_FILES['c_img'.$i]['error'] . '<br />');
    }
    else 
        echo 'added' .$i;
}
```

and what happens when I run:

```
Array ( 
     [c_img1] => Array ( 
           [name] => 010_10 (2).JPG 
           [type] => image/jpeg 
           [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php21CD.tmp 
           [error] => 0 
           [size] => 1080763 
        ) 
     [c_img2] => Array ( 
           [name] => 011_11 (2).JPG 
           [type] => image/jpeg 
           [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php2383.tmp 
           [error] => 0 
           [size] => 612926 
        ) 
     [c_img3] => Array ( 
           [name] => 014_14 (2).JPG 
           [type] => image/jpeg 
           [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php247E.tmp 
           [error] => 0 
           [size] => 975170 
        ) 
     [c_img4] => Array ( 
           [name] => 015_15 (2).JPG 
           [type] => image/jpeg 
           [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php2616.tmp 
           [error] => 0 
           [size] => 1180438 
        ) 
     [c_img5] => Array ( 
           [name] => 016_16 (2).JPG 
           [type] => image/jpeg 
           [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php27FB.tmp 
           [error] => 0 
           [size] => 1142986 
        )
```

)

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../images/cards/356): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache2\htdocs\test\libs\sc.php on line 26 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php21CD.tmp' to '../images/cards/356' in C:\Apache2\htdocs\test\libs\sc.php on line 26 File Error: 0

Comment: What is the value of `$i` just before your `if` statement executes?

Comment: 1, sorry I forgot to change that. It's in a for loop because I'm trying to upload multiple images with it.

Comment: that just prints out "Array()"

Comment: Did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute for the <form> element?

Comment: then you have no file being uploaded, please post the form and perhaps the full php

Comment: sc.php first line, put     print_r($_FILES);exit('end');

Comment: "Array ( ) end" is what printed

Comment: It's `$_FILES["c_img$i"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_FILES["c_img$i"]["temp_name"]`. It doesn't solve the problem, but just in case...
And put an input text and var_dump($_POST) to see if the form works.

Comment: the only thing left i can think of is file uploads being disabled. check php.ini

Comment: add to top: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Like @Dagon said, `file_uploads` must be set to `On` in php.ini.
(`file_uploads = On`)

Comment: still just "Array ( ) end" I'll go look at php.ini

Comment: when you are validating that file_uploads is enabled verify the post_max_size and  upload_max_filesize fields are large enough for your needs as well

Comment: is the url publicly available? not sure it would help, but i could take a look.

Comment: @i_forgot they are both set at 16M

Comment: and since you are uploading mutliple images at once do they exceed that?

Comment: @i_forget I don't think so, 16M and the biggest image is 1.6MB and I'm only uploading 5 at a time

Comment: i hope you have tried with just one small file

Comment: well i took that exact form and threw it up on my webserver and the contents of the $_FILES does dump out as expected so theres that

Comment: not sure what I did but the output changed, editing the post

Comment: bingo, the rest should be easy.

Comment: @Dagon agreed ;) I think I got it from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move uploaded files. <s>Second, `$_FILES['c_img'.$i]["temp_name"]`, if I remember correctly, is an array, which means you need to access it: `$_FILES['c_img'.$i]["temp_name"][0];`.</s> (Turned out that this was inaccurate)

### Some basic debugging suggestions

- Have you confirmed that PHP returns true for `is_dir('../images/cards/');`
- Have you tried adding a file extension (shouldn't matter, but sometimes Windows gets crotchety and it is a good practice nevertheless)? You can either just assign `.jpg` or you can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to grab the extension from `$_FILES['c_img'.$i]["name"];`

Comment: it's still doing the same thing with that